# Are there Old Testament Scriptures that mention salvation for the Gentiles?

Tags: soteriology, old-testament, gentile

I'm wondering if there are any passages/prophecies about salvation for the Gentile world in the Old Testament. If you know any, please share.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**YES**, there are!

The footnote in my NLT Bible for [Acts 11:1](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=acts%2011:1&version=NLT) has a list of Old Testament verses that say that salvation is for *all* people, not just the Jews. Below, I've reproduced the list and for two of them, I've directly quoted them because they're the clearest and most direct with regards to this topic.

- [Genesis 12:3](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=genesis%2012:3&version=NLT)
- [Psalm 22:27](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=psalm%2022:27&version=NLT)
- [Isaiah 42:4](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=isaiah%2042:4&version=NLT)
- [Isaiah 49:6](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=isaiah%2049:6&version=NLT)

> [**Isaiah 49:6 (NLT)**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=isaiah%2049:6&version=NLT)
>   <sup>6</sup>      He says, “You will do more than restore the people of Israel to me.
>                I will make you a light to the Gentiles,
>                and you will bring my salvation to the ends of the earth.”

- [Isaiah 56:3-7](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=isaiah%2056:3-7&version=NLT)
- [Isaiah 60:1-3](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=isaiah%2060:1-3&version=NLT)
- [Jeremiah 16:19-21](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=jeremiah%2016:19-21&version=NLT)
- [Zechariah 2:11](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Zechariah%202:11&version=NLT)

> [**Zechariah 2:11 (NLT)**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Zechariah%202:11&version=NLT)
>
> <sup>11</sup> Many nations will join themselves to the Lord on that day, and they, too, will be my people. I will live among you, and you will know that the Lord of Heaven’s Armies sent me to you.

- [Malachi 1:11](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=malachi%201:11&version=NLT)
- [Romans 15:9-12](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=romans%2015:9-12&version=NLT) (These are different wordings of Psalm 18:49, Deuteronomy 32:43, Psalm 117:1, and Isaiah 11:10.)

Comment: I haven't looked up the context for each verse yet, but aren't most of these dealing with prophecy pointing towards the future when all Christians are meeting God in Heaven? In which case, couldn't the people from all nations only be added *after* Christ and only Jews from *before* Christ?

Answer (score 1):

The first promise to the Gentiles was given to Adam and Eve (Gen.3:15) who were not Jews. The second promise was given to Japheth, the son of Noah who was father to the Gentiles (Gen.9:27).Shem was the father of the Jews (Gen.9:26). This was later confirmed by Isaiah (Isa.54). And I might add two more things. The word Jew was given to Israel by the Gentiles after the Tribe of Judah. The Jewish people are actually of Syrian decent according to Scripture (Due.26:5). As for praying for Israel we should pray as we do for all men but asking God to bless Israel is a sin. Note (2 John 2:7-11). Only those that are in Christ are of Israel "seed" (Gal.3:16) and (Gal.3:27-29). Let Gods Word be true and every man a liar that does not agree with it. God bless those that are in Christ the Son of God.

Comment: You were doing great for site guidelines until "As for praying for Israel". On this site, we don't make those decisions. We keep questions from asking in that manner, and we usually delete answers that answer in that manner. You can [edit] this to be in better line with site guidelines. Please see [What Christianity.StackExchange is (and more importantly, what it isn't)](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1379) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809) for reference.